# Any significant performance improvement by using bitwise operators instead of plain int sums in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, int, bit-manipulation

I started working with C# a few weeks ago and I'm now in a situation where I need to build up a "bit set" flag to handle different cases in an algorithm. I have thus two options:

```
    enum RelativePositioning
    {
        LEFT = 0,
        RIGHT = 1,
        BOTTOM  = 2,
        TOP = 3,
        FRONT = 4,
        BACK = 5
    }

    pos = ((eye.X < minCorner.X ? 1 : 0) << (int) RelativePositioning.LEFT)
        + ((eye.X > maxCorner.X ? 1 : 0) << (int) RelativePositioning.RIGHT)
        + ((eye.Y < minCorner.Y ? 1 : 0) << (int) RelativePositioning.BOTTOM)
        + ((eye.Y > maxCorner.Y ? 1 : 0) << (int) RelativePositioning.TOP)
        + ((eye.Z < minCorner.Z ? 1 : 0) << (int) RelativePositioning.FRONT)
        + ((eye.Z > maxCorner.Z ? 1 : 0) << (int) RelativePositioning.BACK);
```

Or:

```
    enum RelativePositioning
    {
        LEFT = 1,
        RIGHT = 2,
        BOTTOM  = 4,
        TOP = 8,
        FRONT = 16,
        BACK = 32
    }

    if (eye.X < minCorner.X) { pos += (int) RelativePositioning.LEFT;   }
    if (eye.X > maxCorner.X) { pos += (int) RelativePositioning.RIGHT;  }
    if (eye.Y < minCorner.Y) { pos += (int) RelativePositioning.BOTTOM; }
    if (eye.Y > maxCorner.Y) { pos += (int) RelativePositioning.TOP;    }
    if (eye.Z > maxCorner.Z) { pos += (int) RelativePositioning.FRONT;  }
    if (eye.Z < minCorner.Z) { pos += (int) RelativePositioning.BACK;   }
```

I could have used something as `((eye.X > maxCorner.X) << 1)` but C# does not allow implicit casting from bool to int and the ternary operator was similar enough. My question now is: is there any performance improvement in using the first version over the second?

Thank you
Tommaso

Comment: benchmark before performing micro-optimisations

Comment: Agree with Mitch Wheat. Also prefer readability over performance, unless you can prove a bottleneck with a profiler.

Comment: "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil"
Donald Knuth

Comment: Any reason you're not using an enum with the Flag attribute?

Comment: @ Phil: probably because I didn't know about this option :) anyway any good advice is welcome.

Comment: @ Cagdas: I'm going to repeat this process for at least 10K times in a very short time (as short as possible) so I guess that any small optimization is ok. Moreover, I'm actually optimizing, this improvement is not premature, it is in working code.

Comment: As we're micro-optimizing, what about "|=" instead of "+=" in your second example (but profile!), and adding some "else"s (when x<min it's probably not also >max, so use an 'else if' there).

Comment: 10,000 times is not a large number of iterations...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The inline `if` operator (`?`, `:`) will generate nearly the same IL as the standard `if` list in the second example. The only difference you will see here are the particular operations the processor will be doing, and I can bet that `ADD` is quicker than `SHL`.
Since you're going to be adding the results anyway, I would opt for the second example (plus it makes it far easier to read).

***EDIT***
I just checked the IL of both examples, and it goes against what I have said above.
The first example generates far less IL (34 lines less) so you'll have to run a performance test to really determine if it is faster too.

Answer (score 8):

You should definitely use the [Flags attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) for your enum. That way it would look something like that:

```
[Flags]
public enum RelativePositionings
{
    None = 0,
    Left = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Bottom  = 4,
    Top = 8,
    Front = 16,
    Back = 32
}
```

With this you can do such things like:

```
var position = RelativePositionings.Left | RelativePositionings.Front;
```

and check for each state by:

```
if(position.HasFlag(RelativePositioning.Left))
{
    //To do: if left bit is set?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Significantly faster? no. Slightly faster? A little bit.